# Getting the pages count from a printer through command line

Tags: windows, command-line, printer

I'm planning to automate the process of getting the page count collection of every single printer connected to the network (about 40 printers). Right now I'm using *SmartDeviceMonitor for Admin (by Ricoh)* to manage this, but this is a slow process since I have to click on every single printer to get this information, also, I have to munge the data from the CSV file that this software exports. How to do this through command line in Windows (perhaps a VBScript)?

I am trying to setting up SNMP protocol to PHP to accomplish this, but right now I'm getting problems with the SNMP support because I'm stuck with PHP 5.3

Comment: Have you tried anything yourself?  This would seem close to a  request for code without an effort on your part.  Perhaps editing your question would improve it.

Comment: yes, really sorry for not pointing that out, im trying to setting up SNMP protocol to PHP to accomplish this, but right now im getting problems with the SNMP support because im stuck with php 5.3

Comment: You can list some info with `wmic printer list /format:list`, but I am not saying it lists what you need. And you will need the printers in your _Devices and Printers_.

Comment: There are free apps like Xerox' CentreWareWeb or HP's WebJetAdmin that can do this automatically (at specified times) and email the result to you in a CSV file. You'll still need to extract the data from the CSV though.

Comment: @hdhondt yes the SmartDeviceMonitor does the same thing and at this moment im getting the data through the CSV file, however i find it very complicated to loop through all the CSV file and then extract specific data.

Comment: CWW & WJA will collect info from all the printers and log it into one CSV. You do not need to click on the  printers manually, and you do not need to go through multiple CSVs.

Answer (score 0):

Download Device Manager NX Lite. It is a little clunky, but you can add counters as a column on the front screen, which has a nice, juicy export button on it.

Enjoy.

[Download it from this page.](http://support.ricoh.com/html_gen/util/DM/DM.html)